# Select pair of column where max condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have structure like below:

```
column1, column2, column3, pair1, pair2, pair3
  100      200      150     1      2       3
```

I need to select a column with a maximum value with a pair of it, in this case:
200, 2

Comment: This kind of problem is highly symptomatic of poor schema design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select greatest(column1, column2, column3) as column,
       (case greatest(column1, column2, column3)
            when column1 then pair1
            when column2 then pair2
            when column3 then pair3
        end) as pair
```

Note:  You should probably fix the data model.  Having such "paired" columns is a bad idea.  You should have a separate table with one row per pair.